# Install visual studio 2015 but can't create mvc application

Tags: visual-studio, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015

I recently downloaded Visual Studio 2015. When I wanted to create new project I chose file---new---project and I need to select asp.net mvc4 web application, but I couldn't find it I have only asp.net empty web application

[image]

and when I select it i have this error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to install **Microsoft Web Developer Tools.**
here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935

It will enable MVC templates (and others web tools) for VS.
(maybe also the error goes away)

Send results. Att,

Comment: This. Also, OP I don't think MVC4 or it's tooling (you can still open an MVC4 app in VS2015 but the .cshtml pages will show 'errors' even though the code is fine) will come with the regular install of VS2015. There are other posts on this topic where people explain some work arounds.